# In Camel how can i split a route using xpath on a header

Tags: xpath, apache-camel

As the title suggests, i have a route with a header that contains some xml similar to the following snippet as a string;

```
<files>
  <image_file1>image.png</image_file1>
  <image_file2>image.png</image_file2>
</files>
```

What I'm trying do do is split via xpath using something like the following. As the following suggests when the xml is part of the body, all runs fine:-

```
from(myIncomingQueue)
    .convertBodyTo(String.class, "utf-8")
    .split(xpath("//*[local-name()='files']/*"))
        .setHeader("FilePropertyToRetrieve", xpath("local-name(//*)").stringResult())
        .to(myFileDownloadQueue)
.routeId("COMMON-CON-Attachment_Router-Id");
```

I found a solution using the following:-

```
from(myIncomingQueue)
    .setBody(header("myHeaderWithXml"))
    .convertBodyTo(String.class, "utf-8")
    .split(xpath("//*[local-name()='files']/*"))
        .setHeader("FilePropertyToRetrieve", xpath("local-name(//*)").stringResult())
        .setBody(header("CamelOriginalBody"))
        .to(myFileDownloadQueue)
.routeId("COMMON-CON-Attachment_Router-Id");
```

But would still like to know for learning purposes, if there is a way to do it without moving the header into the body and then reversing  afterwards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes if you read the docs about xpath at: http://camel.apache.org/xpath - then see the section *Using XPath on Headers*

Something alike

```
  .split(xpath("//*[local-name()='files']/*", "myHeaderWithXml"))
```

Comment: Thanks @Claus i did read that page and completely missed that line of text for Java DSL line, did read everything around it hence didn't make sense. Thanks for pointing out :)

Comment: Well I added the java line today. But ppl should not that the XML and Java DSL are based 100% on the same model, so everything you can do in one you can do in the other.

Comment: Thanks Claus, I'm very new to this so not 100% sure on all these conventions yet, and unfortunately we are using version 2.09 still so need to use my work around for now. Cheers once again