# Extract xml using XPath in Camel

Tags: xpath, apache-camel

I have XML similar in structure to the below example stored in a Camel header as a String:

```
<list>
   <library>
      <name>xxx</name>
      <address>
         <line1>aaa</line1>
         <line2>bbb</line2>
         <line3>ccc</line3>
      </address>
   </library>
   <book>
      <author>
         <name>John</name>
         <number>4324234</number>
      </author>
      <title>New Book</title>
      <isbn>dsdaassda</isbn>
   </book>
   <book>...</book>
   <book>...</book>
</list>
```

I would like to extract the library element into another Camel header

```
   <library>
      <name>xxx</name>
      <address>
         <line1>aaa</line1>
         <line2>bbb</line2>
         <line3>ccc</line3>
      </address>
   </library>
```

How can I achieve this using Camel Java DSL?

(My main source of confusion is applying the XPath to an exchange header item rather than the body)

Comment: Do you need the xpath expression ?

Comment: Can normal java code be used here instead of using Camel Java DSL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
.xpath("[your XPath expression]", "[the name of the header to select from]")
```

Your use case could be done like this

```
from("direct:input")
    .setHeader("newHeader").xpath("[your XPath]", "[xmlHeader]")
    .to("...");
```

You can find this also in the [Camel docs](http://camel.apache.org/xpath.html), Section `Using XPath on Headers`.

And it is for example used in this [Camel unit test](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/camel-core/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/builder/xml/XPathHeaderNameTest.java), in the route at the bottom of the file.

Comment: Did you check if this works. Second argument to xpath is not a string, May be it was in older versions. Current version takes a second argument of type `Class<?>`

Comment: Those doc's are old. Check out the latest version and try

Comment: Works like a charm. At least for a `when` condition in a content based router.

Comment: I added an example how to extract the XPath result into a new header.

Comment: which version of apache-camel are you using?

Comment: I use Camel 2.17.3, but since I referenced a Camel unit test from the master branch, I cannot imagine that this does no more work in current versions.

Comment: `.setHeader("result").xpath("/list/library", String.class, "source")` causes the header to contain a DTMNodeList rather than a String. Should the above not return a String? If I then call: `.setHeader("result", simple("${headers.result}", String.class))` it works

Comment: Why do us use this `String.class`? At least in my Camel version I can simply do `.setHeader("result").xpath("/list/library", "source")`. That extracts `/list/library` from the header `source` and writes it into the header `result`

Comment: your code will cause it to be written to result header as a DTMNodeList. I want it as a String but using the String.class parameter still causes a DTMNodeList object to be written to the header

Comment: Ah, now I understand. Well, the type is the result of the XPath selection. I don't know a "direct" way to convert it to a String. But if you use it like a String, it should be converted by Camel. For example if you use it as expression: `simple("header=${in.header.newHeader}")`

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
    XPathExpression xPathExpression = new XPathExpression();
    xPathExpression.setHeaderName("completexml"); //assuming the header name of the xml as completexml
    xPathExpression.setExpression("/list/library");

    from("direct:abc")
         .setHeader("OriginalBody", simple("${body}")) //get original body
         .split(xPathExpression) //split according to xPathExpression
         .setHeader("library", simple("${body}")) //set new header with only library element
         .setBody(simple("${header.OriginalBody}")) //set the original body back
         //.log("${header.completexml}")
         //.log("${header.library}")
         //.log("${body}")
        ;
}
```

As per the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18483320/in-camel-how-can-i-split-a-route-using-xpath-on-a-header), we could give a second argument to xpath which is of type `String`. But With the latest version, I don't see any such method in xpath which takes a second argument as String. May be it is removed in newer versions.

What I am doing is storing the original body in a header(since after split, original body is replaced by the result of split), then replacing it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example of JUnit test:

```
@Override
protected RouteBuilder createRouteBuilder() {
    return new RouteBuilder() {
        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
            from("direct:start")
                    .routeId("xpathTest")
            .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "XML input : \n${body}")
            .setHeader("XNODE").xpath("/list/library", NodeList.class)
            .setBody().xpath("/list/library", NodeList.class)
            .to("log:end?level=INFO&showAll=true&multiline=true");
        }
    };
}
```

Оutput log:

```
2018-03-22 00:50:00,141 [main           ] INFO  end                            - Exchange[
, Id: ID-BlackMirror-10897-1521668997689-0-2
, ExchangePattern: InOnly
, Properties: {CamelCreatedTimestamp=Thu Mar 22 00:49:59 MSK 2018, CamelMessageHistory=[DefaultMessageHistory[routeId=xpathTest, node=log1], DefaultMessageHistory[routeId=xpathTest, node=setHeader1], DefaultMessageHistory[routeId=xpathTest, node=setBody1], DefaultMessageHistory[routeId=xpathTest, node=to1]], CamelToEndpoint=log://end?level=INFO&multiline=true&showAll=true}
, Headers: {breadcrumbId=ID-BlackMirror-10897-1521668997689-0-1, XNODE=org.apache.xml.dtm.ref.DTMNodeList@5acf93bb}
, BodyType: org.apache.xml.dtm.ref.DTMNodeList
, Body: <library>       <name>xxx</name>       <address>          <line1>aaa</line1>          <line2>bbb</line2>          <line3>ccc</line3>       </address>    </library>
, Out: null:
```

So for the header you need an expression:

```
.setHeader("XNODE").xpath("/list/library", NodeList.class)
```

and for the body:

```
.setBody().xpath("/list/library", NodeList.class)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it:

```
.setHeader("yourHeaderName", xpath("//*[local-name()='library']").stringResult())
```

So you will have the library structure for work